# VBScript to convert from HTML to DOCX save a corrupted file,

Tags: html, xml, vbscript

I need to convert a file from HTML to DOCX, so I reused a VBS (found in StackOverflow) I already use for converting from RTF changing the source fileformat to wdOpenFormatWebPages. Target fileformat is 16 (wdFormatDocumentDefault). The  HTML file is the output of an XML transformation to obtain at last step a DOCX file in the simplest way.

With "application.visible=true" I can see that the HTML file is opened correctly, but when it is converted and saved it seems as it is zipped or encrypted as in this chunk of the first lines of text:

"PK     ! 2‘oWf ¥  [Content_Types].xml ¢ (   ´”ËjÃ0E÷…þƒÑ¶ØJº(¥ÄÉ¢ehúŠ4NDõB£¼þ¾ã81¥$14ÉÆ ÏÜ{Ï1ƒÑÚšl µw%ë=–“^i7+Ù×ä-d&á”0ÞAÉ6€l4¼½L60#µÃ’ÍS Oœ£œƒXø Ž*•V$:ÆB~‹ðû^ïKï¸”§Úƒ /P‰…IÙëš~7$"

I also tried to save as wdFormatXMLDocument (12) but the result is the same and it also opens a file browser windows and asks me to save infinite times.

Again, I tried RTF and DOC ouputs but I loose the typographic settings of the original document.

Instead, if I open the HTML file using default or "wdOpenFormatAuto = 0" a popup appears asking to choose the input format (defaulting to HTML) and then saves the DOCX file perfectly.

But I need that this conversion works on a batch of an hundred of files, so it has to work without operator intervention.

It seems that I omit something in the code:

```
'enum wdOpenFormat
const wdOpenFormatAllWord = 6                               'A Microsoft Word format that is backward compatible with earlier versions of Word.
const wdOpenFormatAuto = 0                                  'The existing format.
const wdOpenFormatDocument = 1                              'Word format.
const wdOpenFormatEncodedText = 5                           'Encoded text format.
const wdOpenFormatRTF = 3                                   'Rich text format (RTF).
const wdOpenFormatTemplate = 2                              'As a Word template.
const wdOpenFormatText = 4                                  'Unencoded text format.
const wdOpenFormatOpenDocumentText = 18                     'OpenDocument Text format.
const wdOpenFormatUnicodeText = 5                           'Unicode text format.
const wdOpenFormatWebPages = 7                              'HTML format.
const wdOpenFormatXML = 8                                   'XML format.
const wdOpenFormatAllWordTemplates = 13                     'Word template format.
const wdOpenFormatDocument97 = 1                            'Microsoft Word 97 document format.
const wdOpenFormatTemplate97 = 2                            'Word 97 template format.
const wdOpenFormatXMLDocument = 9                           'XML document format.
const wdOpenFormatXMLDocumentSerialized = 14                'Open XML file format saved as a single XML file.
const wdOpenFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled = 10              'XML document format with macros enabled.
const wdOpenFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabledSerialized = 15    'Open XML file format with macros enabled saved as a single XML file.
const wdOpenFormatXMLTemplate = 11                          'XML template format.
const wdOpenFormatXMLTemplateSerialized = 16                'Open XML template format saved as a XML single file.
const wdOpenFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled = 12              'XML template format with macros enabled.
const wdOpenFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabledSerialized = 17    'Open XML template format with macros enabled saved as a single XML file.


'enum WdSaveFormat
const wdFormatDocument = 0 rem <-- DOC
const wdFormatDocument97 = 0
const wdFormatTemplate = 1
const wdFormatTemplate97 = 1
const wdFormatText = 2
const wdFormatTextLineBreaks = 3
const wdFormatDOSText = 4
const wdFormatDOSTextLineBreaks = 5
const wdFormatRTF = 6
const wdFormatUnicodeText = 7
const wdFormatEncodedText = 7
const wdFormatHTML = 8
const wdFormatWebArchive = 9
const wdFormatFilteredHTML = 10
const wdFormatXML = 11
const wdFormatXMLDocument = 12  rem  <-- DOCX
const wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled = 13
const wdFormatXMLTemplate = 14
const wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled = 15
const wdFormatDocumentDefault = 16
const wdFormatPDF = 17
const wdFormatXPS = 18
const wdFormatFlatXML = 19
const wdFormatFlatXMLMacroEnabled = 20
const wdFormatFlatXMLTemplate = 21
const wdFormatFlatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled = 22



Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
For I = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1

    FullName = objArgs(I)
    FileName = Left(objArgs(I), InstrRev(objArgs(I), ".") )

    'set objWordBook = objWord.documents.Open(FullName)
    set objWordBook = objWord.documents.Open(FullName,,,,,,,,,wdOpenFormatWebPages)

    objWord.application.visible=true
    objWord.application.displayalerts=true

    objWordBook.SaveAs FileName & "docx", wdFormatDocumentDefault
    objWordbook.close

    set objWordBook = Nothing

Next
objWord.Quit
```

Thank you for any help you would give.

Comment: Not complete obvious what you are asking. 
What is not working? On what do you need help?
To be clear .docx is compressed file-format using zip. For more info, see https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/

Comment: I need to obtain a readable docx. The same I obtain when I open the HTML file using default or "wdOpenFormatAuto = 0" and then I'm asked choose manually from the opening file format popup or when I convert from RTF. The rest of code is the same, but in those cases it works.